# Jetpack Compose empty string in WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The variable `singleArticle.content` I used in the `AndroidView` is returning an empty value. But if I display it outside `AndroidView` the value appear correctly. Can someone know please what's the issue with my code

```
@Composable
fun ArticleDetailScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: ArticleDetailViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    ...
    CustomWebView(viewModel.article.value)
    ...
}

@Composable
fun CustomWebView(singleArticle: Article) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                loadData(singleArticle.content, "text/html", "UTF-8")
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible reason is that your `singleArticle.content` initially empty, and gets updated after view appears.

[`AndroidView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#AndroidView(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)) `factory` is getting called only once when the view is created. To sync it with Compose state updates, you should use `update` block:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        WebView(context)
    },
    update = {
        it.loadData(singleArticle.content, "text/html", "UTF-8")
    },
)
```